# how to enlarge a specific picture in my code?

Tags: javascript

There are 2 buttons in the code which I have written here: display button and zoom button.

display button works just perfect. but I don’t know how to code zoom button but here is what I want it to do:
when you click on zoom button the last picture which turned hidden must become visible again and the size should grow twice as normal size.
let me clarify myself by two examples:

when you click zoom button after you have pressed display button 3 times, third picture must turn visible and its size must grow twice as normal size.

when you press the zoom button after you have pressed display button 14 times, twelfth picture must appear and grow because it was the last picture that disappeared.

```
<html>

<head>

<style>
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 315px;
}

.table {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<button class="botton";  id="display";>Display</button>
<button class="botton";  id="zoombtn";>Zoom</button>
<br>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/blfy.gif" ALT="Butterflies" id="image-1" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/eye.gif" ALT="Eye" id="image-2" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="IMG/wave.gif" ALT="Wave" id="image-3" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/jungle.gif" ALT="Jungle" id="image-4" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/bridge.gif" ALT="Bridge" id="image-5" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/duck.gif" ALT="Duck" id="image-6" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/egg.gif" ALT="Eggs" id="image-7" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/aurora.gif" ALT="Aurora" id="image-8" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/it.gif" ALT="Technology" id="image-9" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/hill.gif" ALT="Hills" id="image-10" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/string.gif" ALT="strings" id="image-11" class="images" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="IMG/vegi.gif" ALT="vegetables" id="image-12" class="images" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>




</body>


<script>

var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;
document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount < images.length) {
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    hideCount++;
  } else {
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    displayCount++;
    if (displayCount ===  images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: create css classes for the different things you want done.  The add and delete those classes when button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using only javascript might look like this:

```
document.getElementById('zoombtn').onclick = function () {
  if (hideCount > 0) {
    images[hideCount - 1].style.width = images[hideCount - 1].style.width * 2;
  }
}
```

That being said, @DCR is right. It is usually easier and cleaner to add and remove css classes with things like `.classlist.add('yourclass')` and `.classlist.remove('yourclass')` on the target element.